# SSL Error with Ruby on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

Win 7 x64

Whenever I try and install a gem I get an SSL error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.win/quick/Marshal.4.8/responders-2.1.0.gemspec.rz)
```

Basically, I have [this issue](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88), but the fix isn't working for me.

Tried a fresh install of Ruby 2.2.2 from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/), but that gave me gem version 2.4.5. Uninstalled Ruby.

Tried fresh install of Ruby 2.1.6 from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/), got the SSL error. Tried the fix above, no go. Unable to install bundler. Uninstalled Ruby.

Tried a fresh install from [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en). That worked, in the sense it came with bundler. So now I can run `bundle install` and `bundle update` to get gems. But I still can't `gem install xxx` anything.

Comment: Please provide the real URL, this one resolves to a localhost variety (127.0.53.53). Such errors can be just anything and without proper URL don't expect much help.

Comment: Which URL are you referring to?

Comment: The one in the error message: `https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.win/qu...`

Comment: That's the exact error message I get when I run gem install <any gem here>. For example gem install bundler or gem install devise.

Comment: Strange. Then it expects some server at localhost. No idea what this should do.

Comment: If you click on the first link in my post its kind of a known issue? But the fix isn't working for me. Now I know why all Rails developers use Macbooks.

Comment: No, the error in the link is that the verification of the certificate failed, so it already got the certificate from the server. In your case the server replies with `unknown protocol` and will not send the certificate. This can happen when the server expects only TLS1.0+ clients but the client uses SSL3.0 or similar situations. If you have a web server locally running on your system maybe it infers with some stuff the installation tries, so you might try to stop the server.

Answer (score 5):

Try to update the rubygems first:

1. `C:\> gem install rubygems-update -s http://rubygems.org`
2. `C:\> update_rubygems`

Then try to install gem again:

`C:\> gem install bundler`

Comment: the first line results in a warning: `WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned
=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (htt
ps://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed`. Being a warning means there was no error?

Comment: @knocte I think your warning message is different from the message in question.

Comment: ah yeah sorry, I should have posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973328/unable-to-download-data-from-rubygems/39983610#comment68696033_39983610 however, that other question is in Linux and I'm getting that error in Windows

Comment: @WilliamNotowidagdo I received the same warning. But following the instructions still resolved my error. 

What I can't understand is why RubyGems are broken on a clean install from RubyInstaller.org.

Comment: @Benjamin that I can not answer :-)